# Issue while formatting columns in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have pandas data frame `(df)` with 3 columns.

```
rds_cur.execute("""select * from risk  """)
cust= rds_cur.fetchall()
col_names = []
for i in rds_cur.description:
    col_names.append(i[0])
df= pd.DataFrame(cust, columns=col_names)
```

**Orginal Dataframe format while reading from table**

```
df.head(3)
id title_name  block_name
1  [""]          [""]   
12 ["expired"]   ["expired"]
25  [""]         ["expired"]
```

**Expected Format**

```
df.head(3)

id title_name  block_name
1  []          []   
12 [expired]   [expired]
25  []         [expired]
```

How could this be done.

Comment: your dataframes are ambiguous, please provide the output of `df.head(3).to_dict()`

Comment: @mozway, here is the request one `{'id': {0: '16246956WAW', 1: '8700454JED', 2: '10886137CNTXG'},
 'title_name ': {0: '[""]', 1: '["expired"]', 2: '[""]'},
 'block_name': {0: '[""]', 1: '["expired"]', 2: '["expired"]'}}`

Answer (score 0):

If string and not list

```
df = df.replace(regex={'"':''})
```